# Python - Combine text data from group of file by filename

Tags: python, text-files

I have below list of text files , I wanted to combine group of files like below

Inv030001.txt - should have all data of files starting with Inv030001

Inv030002.txt - should have all data of files starting with Inv030002

[image]

I tried below code but it's not working

```
filenames = glob(textfile_dir+'*.txt')
for fname in filenames:
filename = fname.split('\\')[-1]
current_invoice_number =  (filename.split('_')[0]).split('.')[0]
prev_invoice_number = current_invoice_number
with open(textfile_dir + current_invoice_number+'.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for eachfile in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(textfile_dir), '*[!'+current_invoice_number+'].txt'):
        current_invoice_number = (eachfile.split('_')[0]).split('.')[0]
        if(current_invoice_number == prev_invoice_number):
            with open(textfile_dir+eachfile) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
            prev_invoice_number = current_invoice_number
        else:
            with open(textfile_dir+eachfile) as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)
            prev_invoice_number = current_invoice_number
            #break;
```

Comment: This line of code:  `current_invoice_number =  (filename.split('_')[0]).split('.')[0]` doesn't look right.  Perhaps just `current_invoice_number =  filename.split('_')[0]`?

Comment: When doing stuff like this you really should break it down into tasks and test every task along the way. Your first task would simply be getting the filenames. Then move on to getting the file contents. Then move on to merging the file contents. It's actually hard to mess up this way, because with each new task you have eliminated the previous tasks as being an issue. Fleshing out the entire idea in one go means you have to backtrack and figure out where the problem is, but it could be anywhere, and you end up treating it all like tasks to find the problem.

Comment: @Mark ~ you are correct but that is not the issue. there just won't be a dot so the string doesn't change, at all.

Comment: Code posted above works for single iteration, however for next iteration glob returns next file which is already processed in previous iteration. I tried skipping and breaking but no success.

Comment: @ZKS ~ aside from my last suggestion (which you should do now and forever), your names are so long that it's making your code very dense and hard to keep track of. In a way, you could say that you have made this as complicated as possible. If you take my advice you could rewrite and fix this thing in about 15 minutes (or less). You don't need stack for this. You just need to think clearly and do one step at a time.

Comment: Thanks for help, I found the solution by breaking it down. Added as answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question? My version will append the data from "like" invoice numbers to a .txt file named with just the invoice number. In other words, anything that starts with "Inv030001" will have it's contents appended to "Inv030001.txt". The idea being that you likely don't want to overwrite files and possibly destroy them if your write logic had a mistake.

I actually recreated your files to test this. I did exactly what I suggested you do. I just treated every part as a separate task and built it up to this, and in doing that the script became far less verbose and convoluted. I labeled all of my comments with `task` to pound it in that this is just a series of very simple things.

I also renamed your vars to what they actually are. For instance, `filenames` aren't filenames, at all. They are entire paths.

```
import os
from glob import glob

#you'll have to change this path to yours
root  = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'texts/')

#sorting this may be redundant 
paths = sorted(glob(root+'*.txt'))

for path in paths:
    #task: get filename
    filename = path.split('\\')[-1]
    #task: get invoice number
    invnum   = filename.split('_')[0]
    #task: open in and out files
    with open(f'{root}{invnum}.txt', 'a') as out_, open(path, 'r') as in_:
        #task: append in contents to out
        out_.write(in_.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code may have had a little too much complications in it.  And so, the idea is that for every file in the directory, just add it's contents (that is, append) to the invoice file.

```
from glob import glob, fnmatch
import os
textfile_dir="invs" + os.sep  # # I changed this to os.sep since I'm on a MAC - hopefully works in windows, too
filenames = glob(textfile_dir+'*.txt')
for fname in filenames:
  filename = fname.split(os.sep)[-1]  
  current_invoice_number =  (filename.split('_')[0]).split('.')[0]
  with open(textfile_dir + current_invoice_number+'.txt', 'a') as outfile:
      with open(fname) as infile:
          for line in infile:
              outfile.write(line)
```

Some room for improvement:

1. If you created your accumulation files in a different directory, there would be less of a chance of you picking them up when you run this program again (we are using append `'a'` when we open the files for writing.
2. The order of the files is not preserved with glob (AFAIK).  This may not be great for having deterministic results.

Comment: this solution is going in loop and adding repetitive data.. I added found solution

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working code, if someone is looking for same solution

```
filenames = glob(textfile_dir+'*.txt')
dd = defaultdict(list)
for filename in filenames:
name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
name = name.split('\\')[-1].split('_')[0]
dd[name].append(filename)

for key, fnames in dd.items():
with open(textfile_dir+key+'.txt', "w") as newfile:
     for line in fileinput.FileInput(fnames):
         newfile.write(line)
```